# Convert ClamAV log output to JSON

Tags: json

I'm working on a project using ClamAV to scan several CentOS 7 machines and a Ubuntu 16.04 machine. We need to integrate the output into a SIEM solution, but Clam's output is incompatible;

```
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 33840
Scanned directories: 145
Scanned files: 226
Infected files: 1
Data scanned: 54.22 MB
I/O buffer size: 131072 bytes
Time: 20.831 sec (0 m 20 s)
```

I imagine its possible to convert this output to json using pythong, but being relatively new to python I'm not sure where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
$ awk -vmax=$(wc -l < file) -F: '
    BEGIN{print "{"}
    NR>1{
        gsub(/^ /, "", $2);
        printf "%s",  "\t\042"$1"\042:\042"$2"\042"
        if (NR<max) {print ","}else{print "\n"}
    }
    END{print "}"}
' file
```

### Output:

```
{
    "Known viruses":"33840",
    "Scanned directories":"145",
    "Scanned files":"226",
    "Infected files":"1",
    "Data scanned":"54.22 MB",
    "I/O buffer size":"131072 bytes",
    "Time":"20.831 sec (0 m 20 s)"

}
```

Answer (score 3):

here is a `python` solution

```
def clam_result_str_to_json(clam_result_str):

    clam_result_list = clam_result_str.split("\n")
    clam_result_list.remove('')

    results_marker = \
        clam_result_list.index("----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------")

    hit_list = clam_result_list[:results_marker]
    summary_list = clam_result_list[(results_marker + 1):]

    r_dict = { "hits": hit_list }
    for s in summary_list:
        # in case of blank lines
        if not s:
            continue
        split_index = [c == ':' for c in s].index(True)
        k = s[:split_index].lower()
        k = k.replace(" ", "_")
        v = s[(split_index + 1):].strip(" ")
        r_dict[k] = v

    return r_dict
```

when clam is invoked with the `-i` option, this function takes this

```
/tmp/foo.tar.gz: Eicar-Signature FOUND

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Infected files: 1
Time: 0.004 sec (0 m 0 s)
Start Date: 2022:03:25 21:40:15
End Date:   2022:03:25 21:40:15
```

and turns it into this:

```
{
    "end_date": "2022:03:25 21:40:15",
    "hits": [
        "/tmp/foo.tar.gz: Eicar-Signature FOUND"
    ],
    "infected_files": "1",
    "start_date": "2022:03:25 21:40:15",
    "time": "0.004 sec (0 m 0 s)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution to make a json object where keys use underscore notation, string values are quoted, and numbers are not quoted:

```
#!/bin/bash

input_file="scan.log";
output_file="result.log";

# Remove everything before and including "----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------"
process=$(sed '1,/----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------/d' "$input_file");
# Make object keys lowercase and add quotation
process=$(echo "$process" | sed -e 's/\([^:]*\):/"\L\1":/');
# Make object keys underscore notation
process=$(echo "$process" | sed -e 's/\([a-z]\)\s\+\([a-z]\)/\1_\2/');
# Put quotes around answers
process=$(echo "$process" | sed -e 's/:\s*\(.\+\)$/:"\1"/');
# Remove quotes from numbers
process=$(echo "$process" | sed -e 's/:"\([0-9]\+\.\?[0-9]*\)"$/:\1/');
# Add comma to end each line
process=$(echo "$process" | sed -e 's/:\(.\+\)$/:\1,/');
# Remove comma from last line of file
process=$(echo "$process" | sed -e '${s/,$//}');
echo "{$process}" > $output_file;

cat $output_file;
```

My `scan.log`:

```
/etc/alternatives/unlzma.1.gz: Symbolic link
/etc/alternatives/pinentry: Symbolic link
/etc/alternatives/vi: Symbolic link
/etc/vtrgb: Symbolic link
/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf: Symbolic link
/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf: Symbolic link
/etc/localtime: Symbolic link

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 8686138
Engine version: 0.103.11
Scanned directories: 16.0
Scanned files: 596
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 2.66 MB
Data read: 1.09 MB (ratio 2.45:1)
Time: 64.425 sec (1 m 4 s)
Start Date: 2024:03:08 00:38:47
End Date:   2024:03:08 00:39:51
```

My `result.log`:

```
{"known_viruses":8686138,
"engine_version":"0.103.11",
"scanned_directories":16.0,
"scanned_files":596,
"infected_files":0,
"data_scanned":"2.66 MB",
"data_read":"1.09 MB (ratio 2.45:1)",
"time":"64.425 sec (1 m 4 s)",
"start_date":"2024:03:08 00:38:47",
"end_date":"2024:03:08 00:39:51"}
```